# how to use --libcurl <file>

Tags: curl, libcurl

--libcurl <>

Append this option to any ordinary curl command line, and you will get a libcurl-using C source code written to the file that does the equivalent of what your command-line operation does.This what man page says,but how to use it in Windows?
Please explain with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example line:

```
curl --libcurl test.c -d mooo http://example.org
```

It runs the command and generates a template source code in "test.c" that does the same thing as your command line did, using libcurl.

Comment: ok,i tried this, so i can run test.c as a separate program which will generate same output as the as the curl command? I want this command to execute: curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/document/update/extract?literal.id=12&commit=true" -F"myfile=@C:\solr\document\src\test1\Coding.pdf"  but when used like this: curl --libcurl test.c -d mooo "http://localhost:8080/solr/document/update/extract?literal.id=12&commit=true" -F"myfile=@C:\solr\document\src\test1\Coding.pdf"  it gives error that only one http must be used

Comment: now you're no longer on topic of what you asked, you still must use a valid curl command line to make curl do what you want

Comment: okay, i am sorry, but i need that command to be worked, why is -F not a valid one?? n it does not work, but it is actually curl option.If you could anyway help, that will be appreciated.

Comment: No, that's not what your question here asks.